# Renaming root directory for Android Studio project breaks code

Tags: android-studio

In Android Studio, I wanted to rename the root directory. There was no way to do this within Android Studio, so I exited AS and renamed the folder and then opened the project again. But when I went to run the app, it indicates:

> AndroidManifest.xm does not exist or has incorrect root tag

The manifest does exist, but apparently something breaks by renaming the file. I tried invalidating the cache but that didn't help.

Comment: No surprise, since all the internal references still expect the old path....

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. References shouldn't be made with absolute paths. I even used a tool to scan each file for absolute path names but couldn't find anything. There should be an easy way of renaming your project's root folder without breaking anything.

Comment: You renamed your project **outside** the IDE. You didn't **refactor** it. So, `the old references` haven't been renamed and `still expect the old project name`.

Comment: In Eclipse this is easily done inside the IDE itself, since it refactors the paths automatically. Maybe you can take the old project in Eclipse, refactor the new name and then reimport the project in AS... Or manually rename all your paths in every file. OK, I see you solved it yourself, +1

Comment: The refactor menu item does provide a rename, but that appears to rename only something internally and not the actual folder itself.

Comment: I see, I don't use AS, so I can just imagine.

Answer (score 1):

Closing the project and then removing it from the list and then reimporting the project as a non-Android project corrected the problem. Still, this seems to be a hack. It should be possible to rename the root folder without having to take this approach.

Comment: I m having the same problem in android studio.Dont u think, reimporting the project as a non-Android project, is not in android way, since it is indeed an android studio project. There's a file in .idea/.name which has the directory name but changing that didnt work for me.Do u think this hack is safe ?